# Prove $9\mid (x^2 + y^2) \iff 3\mid x \text{ and } 3\mid y$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

Prove: Let $x, y$ be two non-negative integers. Then $9|(x^2 + y^2)$ if and only if $3|x$ and $3|y$.

General format of proving iff statement.
Proof. 
Part 1, proving $p \implies q$ 
Part 1, proving $q \implies p$ 
Therefore, $p \iff q. \qed$

Comment: Approach $1$ is almost right.  You don't actually say that $3 \mid x$ and $3 \mid y \Rightarrow 9 \mid (x^2+y^2)$.  It's pretty obvious, but in approach $1$, you don't actually say it.  Approach $2$ looks fine to me.

Comment: Are you saying that Approach 2 is good/correct as is? ;o
Also one thing I was wondering, in Approach one you see how when I squared things, I changed to mod 9, would that change to mod 9 like that or stay mod 3?

Comment: Yes, Approach $2$ is correct.  You skipped another step in Approach $1$.  It's not obvious (and in fact not true) that $0, 1, 4$ are the only squares $\pmod 9$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Robert. Much appreciated!

Comment: I'd include the step that says $3 \mid x \Rightarrow 9 \mid x^2$ (etc.), but other than skipped step that it looks right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a (very) slightly different approach, presented more to help you with proof-writing than with the math (which I think you understand).

First, assume $3 \mid x$ and $3 \mid y$.  Then $9 \mid x^2$ and $9 \mid y^2$, so $9 \mid (x^2+y^2)$.  That proves $\Leftarrow$.

Conversely, assume $3 \nmid x$.  Then $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3$.  Since $y^2 \neq 2 \pmod 3$ (no matter what $y$ is), this means $x^2+ y^2 \neq 0 \pmod 3$ so $9 \nmid (x^2+y^2)$.

Finally, if $3 \nmid y$, then we've just proved that $9 \nmid (y^2+x^2)$, so also $9 \nmid (x^2+y^2)$.  This paragraph and the last paragraph prove $\Rightarrow$.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a version of your first approach. Mod $3$, the squares are $0$ and $1$. So how could you add two squares and get $0$ mod $3$? Only if both squares are $0$. In which case, $x$ and $y$ are also each $0$ mod $3$.

Note there is no need to consider "$9$". It's enough that $3$ divides $x^2+y^2$. Also, it's not a contrapositive argument. It is just an examination of the four cases $0+0$, $0+1$, $1+0$, and $1+1$.